# Maximal Eulerian subgraph in a given graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, eulerian-path

Given a graph like the following:

[image: Given graph]

how do I find the maximal Eulerian subgraph? The answer for this case should be (subgraph with blue edges):

[image: Answer]

In general, is there an algorithm to derive this particular subgraph?

Comment: Are you asking for an Eulerian spanning subgraph? [Supereulerian graphs](http://jacobi.math.wvu.edu/~hjlai/Pdf/Catlin_Pdf/Catlin42.pdf)

Comment: Do you mean maximal (no Eulerian subgraph strictly contains it) or maximum (largest Eulerian subgraph there is)?  Because in your example, removing the edge $\{5,6\}$ and adding $\{4,5\}$ and $\{4,6\}$ gives a larger Eulerian subgraph.